# mysql return null if no value on one of the joins

Tags: mysql

I have a sql query with joins i would like to display NULL for "aov.value gazlabel" if no results are returned instead of not returning anything, i tried outer join on left JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS aov but it doesnt return anything.

Query :

```
SELECT pev.`entity_id`,
       pev.`value`,
       aov.`value` gazlabel
FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS pev
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS pe
    ON pe.`entity_id` = pev.`entity_id`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS pei
    ON pei.`entity_id` = pe.`entity_id`
        AND pei.`store_id` = pev.`store_id`
left JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS aov
    ON aov.`option_id` = pei.`value`
        AND aov.`store_id` = pev.`store_id`
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` as ea
    ON ea.`attribute_id` = pei.`attribute_id`
WHERE pev.`attribute_id` = 71
    AND pev.`store_id` IN ("0", "1")
    AND ea.`attribute_code` = "front_label"
    AND pe.`sku` LIKE "C10192"
ORDER BY `pev`.`store_id` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your join looks good. Do you get any rows if you remove that join altogether?

Comment: it works if AND pe.`sku` LIKE "C10192", if just like it to still return the other values and just say NULL if the aov.`value` gazlabel is null

Comment: Do i need a union select?

Comment: @gazZz I think you need to use `LEFT JOIN` on all joins, to make sure you always get the row, albeit with null values on some columns. This is the solution posted by scaisEdge.

Answer (score 1):

could be your match fails for some others tables than aov so use more left  join

```
    SELECT pev.`entity_id`,
           pev.`value`,
           aov.`value` gazlabel
    FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS pev
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS pe
        ON pe.`entity_id` = pev.`entity_id`
           AND pe.`sku` LIKE "C10192"
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS pei
        ON pei.`entity_id` = pe.`entity_id`
            AND pei.`store_id` = pev.`store_id`
    left JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS aov
        ON aov.`option_id` = pei.`value`
            AND aov.`store_id` = pev.`store_id`
    LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute` as ea
        ON ea.`attribute_id` = pei.`attribute_id`
          AND ea.`attribute_code` = "front_label"
    WHERE pev.`attribute_id` = 71
        AND pev.`store_id` IN ("0", "1")
    ORDER BY `pev`.`store_id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

or if only the like condition don't match  reduce the left join only at the first not matching tables

```
    SELECT pev.`entity_id`,
           pev.`value`,
           aov.`value` gazlabel
    FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS pev
    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS pei
        ON pei.`entity_id` = pe.`entity_id`
            AND pei.`store_id` = pev.`store_id`
    INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` as ea
        ON ea.`attribute_id` = pei.`attribute_id`
          AND ea.`attribute_code` = "front_label"
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS pe
        ON pe.`entity_id` = pev.`entity_id`
           AND pe.`sku` LIKE "C10192"
    left JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS aov
        ON aov.`option_id` = pei.`value`
            AND aov.`store_id` = pev.`store_id`
    WHERE pev.`attribute_id` = 71
        AND pev.`store_id` IN ("0", "1")
    ORDER BY `pev`.`store_id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Was gonna say the exact same thing.

Comment: gazlabel can be a label or i want it to be null, so if that select from that join returns nothing it is showing no rows rather than showing the rows  but having gazlabel as null